# How can I get HBaseTestingUtility to find classes in map reduce jobs?

Tags: unit-testing, scala, hadoop, hbase, sbt

We're using cdh3u4, Hadoop and HBase. I'm trying to run a unit test that kicks off a MapReduce job after starting up the miniMapReduceCluster provided by the HBaseTestingUtility.

The jobs fail with this in the map and reducer task stderr logs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Child
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
 Could not find the main class: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.  Program will exit.
java.lang.Throwable: Child Error
```

I've been trying to figure this out for days. I'm guessing its a mis - Configuration and that the cluster is not finding any of my jars due to misconfigured fs / hdfs config values.
My test setup code looks like this (excuse typos as this is translation from Scala):

```
HBaseTestingUtility htest = new HBaseTestingUtility();
Configuration c = htest.getConfiguration();
c.set("hadoop.log.dir", "/tmp/hadoop-test-logs"); // required or else can't start the miniMapReduceCluster
htest.startMiniCluster();
htest.startMiniMapReduceCluster();

// create and run a MapReduce job that works in production but not in test
```

In case this is important, we are using Play! framework 2.0 (which uses SBT) with Specs2 testing framework and Scala. I don't think it should matter (that we aren't using Java + JUnit).

Has anyone seen this before? Any pointers on where to look?

Thanks in advance,

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out we have to manually setup the classpath on the minicuster. This may be an SBT / Ivy thing - since all examples I've seen don't have to do this and are presumably using Maven (and Java).

Here's how I resolved the classpath issue (in Scala):

```
// unit test setup:
val htest = new HBaseTestingUtility
htest.startMiniCluster()

val conf = htest.getConfiguration
conf.set("hadoop.log.dir", "/tmp/hadoop-test-logs") // required to prevent NPE when starting miniMapReduceCluster
htest.startMiniMapReduceCluster()

// Set up cluster classpath:
val fs = FileSystem.get(conf)
val jarsDir = new Path("/tmp/hadoop-test-lib")
fs.mkdirs(jarsDir)

// copy jars over to hdfs and add to classpath:
for (jar <- myjars) {
    val localJarPath = new Path("file://%s".format(jar.getAbsolutePath))
    val hdfsJarPath = new Path("/tmp/hadoop-test-lib/%s".format(jar.getName))
    fs.copyFromLocalFile(localJarPath, hdfsJarPath)
    DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(hdfsJarPath)
}

// now Map and Reduce tasks can find classes
```

Comment: Mark, you also might want to have a look at Scoobi: http://nicta.github.com/scoobi. There are a few testing traits which may make your life easier when running Hadoop jobs: http://nicta.github.com/scoobi/guide/Testing%20guide.html#Testing+guide

Answer (score 0):

I did compile a blog:
http://mevivs.wordpress.com/2012/05/03/perform-crud-over-hbase-using-hbasetestingutilityembeddedhbase/

Have a look at this.

Hope it Helps.

-Vivek